# R clustering results not as expected - have i misunderstood/misused anything?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I am learning to use R to cluster data points and I created a toy example. I use Silhouette statistics to determine an optimal cluster number, but the optimal number it determines is not what i expect. I include all my steps and data as below. I wonder if I have misunderstood/misused anything? I would really appreciate for any comments!

First, data matrix "m" loaded from a file look like this. [image: Data matrix m loaded from a file] Each row is the feature vector of an object

Then R code:

```
d <- dist(m, method="euclidean")
```

The distance matrix looks like this:
[image]

Next perform clustering:

```
clustering <- hclust(d, "average")
```

Then calculate silhouette, for all possible cluster numbers, i.e., 1<=i <=10:

```
sub <- cutree(clustering, k=i) #replace i with 1, 2, 3... 10
si <- silhouette(sub, d)
sm <- summary(si, FUN=mean)
sm  #to print
```

For example, I get the following mean silhouette values for each i:

```
i=1, NaN
i=2, 0.19
i=3, 0.157
....
i=8, 0.09
...
```

The maximum is i=2, suggesting there are two clusters, as below:

[image]

i.e.,

cluster1 = {4}

cluster2 = {all else}

I wonder why it is not predicting 3 clusters as below, which is what I expect to be reasonable:

cluster1 = {4}

cluster2 = {1,2,5,6,7}

cluster3 = {3,8,9,10}

I obtain this outcome by looking at the feature vectors of each object and grouping objects based on the fact that they have at least feature in common that is a non-zero value. Therefore, I cannot understand why cluster2 and cluster3 should be merged, as suggested by the highest silhouette value?

Answer (score 0):

Euclidean distance always considers *all* features.

It does not look for 0 values. They are not special.

Given the large amount of 0 values, you should be using a different distance and/or algorithm.

Comment: thanks, i think that makes sense... but can you suggest something? I tried "manhattan" and "canberra", both gave me unnormalized values. "minkowski" gives identical results as euclidean

Comment: Not surprising: Euclidean is a minkowski norm. You seem to be thinking of maximum norm. But you should try to understand your problem and data, not try to find a random parameter setting that yields the results on this one example.